# Stm32f303vc discovery tim3 is not working

Tags: c, timer, stm32, keil

I would like to configure tim3 ch1 ch2 as encoder mode, I have the same code on tim2( it's also general purpose timer) and it's working good. 
Maybe there's another bits should I set but I cant find them.

I was trying to configure this timer to work without any outputs, just generate interrupt after set period of time but it's not working as well.

```
    //TIM2 CH1 PA0 CH2 PA1 AF1
    //TIM3 CH1 PE2 CH2 PE3 AF2

    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_TIM2EN | RCC_APB1ENR_TIM3EN ;
    RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOAEN | RCC_AHBENR_GPIOEEN;

    GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER0_1 |  GPIO_MODER_MODER1_1;
    GPIOE->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER2_1 |  GPIO_MODER_MODER3_1;

    GPIOA->AFR[0] |= 0X00000011;
    GPIOE->AFR[0] |= 0X00002200;


    TIM2->SMCR = TIM_SMCR_SMS_0;
    TIM2->CCMR1 = TIM_CCMR1_CC1S_0|TIM_CCMR1_CC2S_0;
    TIM2->ARR = 24;
    TIM2->DIER = TIM_DIER_UIE;
    TIM2->CR1= TIM_CR1_CEN;

    TIM3->SMCR = TIM_SMCR_SMS_0 ;
    TIM3->CCMR1 = TIM_CCMR1_CC1S_0 | TIM_CCMR1_CC2S_0;
    TIM3->ARR = 24;
    TIM3->DIER = TIM_DIER_UIE;
    TIM3->CR1= TIM_CR1_CEN ;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlBeH.jpg)

Comment: "Not working" is not a sufficiently technical description of the problem. What other diagnostics can you give?

Comment: I was trying a lot of to configure it but I didn't get any replay from this timer. I was trying to generate pwm or blink led after time.

Comment: I have added photo from debuger

Comment: That's not a problem so much as it is a screenshot of some values. You're going to need to do more diagnostics here.

Comment: There's the datasheet my microcontroler https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f303vc.pdf  on page 36 is information about pin who I can configure as tim3 and it's PE2 and PE3 but in the next page is the same for PA6 and PA7. What's pin is default set to work as timer input? Should I make something like remapping or turn on any register?

Comment: You don't need any I/O pins to generate an interrupt on the update (overflow) event. Later, if you'd like to use timer I/O, load the board in STM32CubeMX to let it pick a usable pin for you. There is no default, any one of PA6, PC6 or PE2 can be assigned to TIM3_CH1, none is preferred over the other as far as the MCU is concerned. You should however pick one that is not connected to something else, CubeMX takes this into account.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>**Set `SMCR` to `0`**</strike>

Your code sets both timers to encoder mode 1, see the description of the `SMCR` register in the reference manual.

> 0001: Encoder mode 1 - Counter counts up/down on TI1FP1 edge depending on TI2FP2 level.

In this mode, the timer counter is incremented or decremented by the signals on then CH1 and CH2 input, instead of the internal clock. There must be some other component on the board, or line noise when they are unconnected, that managed to trigger TIM2 a few times.

**PE2 is connected to an output of another IC**

Check the schematics in the board user manual. PE2 is connected to the DRDY **output** of the onboard accelerometer.

You can use the CubeMX tool to find available pins for TIM3. Select your board in the Board Selector screen, it will show that PE2 and PE3 are already connected to something.

Set TIM3 combined channels to encoder mode, it will assign some free pins to the timer. You can then hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and click on the pin to see alternatives (they will blink in blue), and you can drag the pin assignments with the mouse.

Comment: TIM2 and TIM3  don't have united register (TIM3->SMCR and TIM2->SMCR its not the same). They are conifigurating independly. Im sure the TIM2 works propertly because I saw the changing counter in debug mode while I was rotating my encoder. What else I will try to set TIM3 in another empty project with this configuration and it's still not working :/

Comment: Sorry, it looks like I've missed the bit about the encoders.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find a solution :) 
If I assign TIM3 CH1 to PB4 and CH2 to PB5 it's work good, but I don't understand why, can someone explain it ?